# Error (object._d_arraysetlengthTImpl not found) while building D project on MacOS

Tags: macos, d

I was trying to build existing Dlang project on my home Mac. But I am getting this error. I haven't find anything about it.

```
$ dub build
Running pre-generate commands for vibe-d:tls...
Performing "debug" build using dmd for x86_64.
tinyendian 0.2.0: target for configuration "library" is up to date.
dyaml 0.8.0: building configuration "library"...
/Library/D/dmd/src/phobos/std/uni.d(935,32): Error: object._d_arraysetlengthTImpl not found. The current runtime does not support resizing arrays, or the runtime is corrupt.
/Library/D/dmd/src/phobos/std/uni.d(968,32): Error: object._d_arraysetlengthTImpl not found. The current runtime does not support resizing arrays, or the runtime is corrupt.
/Library/D/dmd/src/phobos/std/uni.d(4064,18): Error: template instance std.uni.MultiArray!(BitPacked!(uint, 13LU), BitPacked!(bool, 1LU)).MultiArray.length!0LU error instantiating
/Library/D/dmd/src/phobos/std/uni.d(4312,37):        instantiated from here: TrieBuilder!(bool, dchar, 1114112, sliceBits!(8LU, 21LU), sliceBits!(0LU, 8LU))
/Library/D/dmd/src/phobos/std/regex/internal/ir.d(26,14):        instantiated from here: CodepointSetTrie!(13, 8)
/Library/D/dmd/src/phobos/std/uni.d(935,32): Error: object._d_arraysetlengthTImpl not found. The current runtime does not support resizing arrays, or the runtime is corrupt.
/Library/D/dmd/src/phobos/std/uni.d(968,32): Error: object._d_arraysetlengthTImpl not found. The current runtime does not support resizing arrays, or the runtime is corrupt.
/Library/D/dmd/src/phobos/std/uni.d(4064,18): Error: template instance std.uni.MultiArray!(BitPacked!(uint, 13LU), BitPacked!(bool, 1LU)).MultiArray.length!1LU error instantiating
/Library/D/dmd/src/phobos/std/uni.d(4312,37):        instantiated from here: TrieBuilder!(bool, dchar, 1114112, sliceBits!(8LU, 21LU), sliceBits!(0LU, 8LU))
/Library/D/dmd/src/phobos/std/regex/internal/ir.d(26,14):        instantiated from here: CodepointSetTrie!(13, 8)
dmd failed with exit code 1.
```

Can somebody pls help?
I am using these:
MacOS 10.15.4
DMD64 v2.091.1
DUB 1.20.1

Comment: have you ever installed another version of dmd before? this is sometimes caused by a version mismatch between the source and installed bin library.

Comment: yea, there was some other installation before.. Now I used homebrew to install new version, but maybe the old version was installed differently.. How can i check this?

Comment: yeah that's probably it... blargh I don't know the exact solution myself but i'd prolly suggest doing an uninstall thing if it is there, then deleting that /Library/D directory and /etc/dmd.conf if it is present, then try installing the new one again. I'm not a mac user myself though. Another thing you can do is run `dmd` without arguments btw and scroll up, it will tell you teh version it ran there and the config file locaton a few lines down. If either of those aren't what you expected maybe clearing that before the reinstall will help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to Adam D. Ruppe.

It looks like there was a problem with previously installed version of dmd.
Solved by:

- brew uninstall dub
- brew uninstall dmd
- delete /Library/D directory
- brew install dmd
- brew install dub